# CS:GO lvl up weapon drops

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So I keep asking myself, wether there is a correlation between the rank I have and the reward I get. is it the same when I level up to lvl 2 and when I lvl up to lvl 25?

Comment: These are two separate questions, I'd recommend removing one and posting it as another question

Comment: done, sry, thought they are kinda related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correlation between your matchmaking rank *or* profile rank and the quality of weapon drops you receive.

Weapon drops are purely randomized in a way that makes sense: the lowest-quality weapon skins (*industrial grade*) are the most common while the highest-quality weapon skins (*covert*) are the rarest. The chances of getting a covert skin in any match are less than 0.1%.

Note: This is separate from Operation-induced drops. In Operations, such as Bloodhound, ranking up gets you a Bloodhound drop. These will automatically be at least slightly better than any non-Operation drop.

Comment: i am not talking about my matchmaking rank, I talk about the level of my account (you gain xp for matches, at certain points you level up)

Comment: @rqstr Sorry, misread. It's still the same for profile rank, but I'll update my answer anyway.

Comment: Can you get covert items in normal matchmaking?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Yes. You can find videos of people getting Dragon Lore as a drop.

Comment: @Adam Impossible to get now through a regular drop.